# Change Database schema but keep data access compatible

Tags: sql, triggers

I'm working on a fairly large project rewriting software to .Net C#. The original software was written in Visual DataFlex for DOS and used to store data in a separate files for each table, we now use a driver program for the original software that means the data base is now in SQL. But what I think really needs to change in the data base schema. What I wanted to know is could we write SQL triggers for the database so when the driver program tries to access the old data base schema we get and set the data in a new data base schema as well so we can change it but keep everything working. I haven't had to use triggers before so I am not sure if this is something that would work or what disadvantages or problems it could have.

Comment: You could use Views and [`Instead of`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188601(v=sql.105).aspx) triggers but when you do a replacement of a working legacy system you really need to pick your battles. I would keep the DB schema (as flawed as it may be) and focus on the C# rewrite.

Comment: I would agree with @Conrad Frix: If you are rewriting a working legacy system, you typically don't want to deal with a changing structure and new system at the same time.  Write a high-quality n-tiered system over the existing schema.  Then, when you no longer have to deal with the legacy system, it will be much easier to change the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the project that was rewriting this system but I have used Views for changing the way the data structure appears since then, and used triggers a bit more and I would agree with the comments on this questions now that changing the schema is a big job and it is better to just focus on rewriting the code first and write that in a way that can handle a change in the schema later on.